# MySQL Highscores - User's Personal Ranks: Duplicate Entries Causing Incorrect Values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently creating a page in PHP that will display a user and their ranks in my site's highscores.

However, I have one field that is different from the rest and isn't functioning as intended.

Here is my table:

```
-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `playerstats`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `playerstats`;
CREATE TABLE `playerstats` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gamelevel` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `overall` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `overallxp` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

...and some example data:

```
INSERT INTO `playerstats` VALUES ('14950', '123', '1495', '129825211')
INSERT INTO `playerstats` VALUES ('28967', '124', '1495', '127168799')
INSERT INTO `playerstats` VALUES ('95848', '121', '1495', '108481173')
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT count(*) + 1 FROM (SELECT uid, overall, overallxp, gamelevel FROM playerstats GROUP BY playerstats.uid) AS x WHERE overall > (SELECT overall FROM playerstats WHERE uid = ". $userid .")"
```

...and $userid is:

```
$userid = (int) $_GET['searched'];
```

Now, when I navigate to the personal highscores of userid14950, it displays the correct overall ranking for that user because they are the person with the highest overallxp for their overall. However, when I visit the personal highscores of userid28967 or userid95848, their overall rank is the same as userid14950 for some reason (most likely because I don't account for users with the same overall result).

My question is: how would I go about making it so if two (or more) users share the same overall, they have their correct rank displayed, and not a duplicate one?

So that's about it.
Any help is very much appreciated :)

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Sooo... what's your question?

Comment: all the players have the same overall. in your query the only filter you impose is the overall and not the overallxp

Comment: @Dancrumb: Sorry, haha.  My question is: how would I go about making it so if two (or more) users share the same overall, they have their correct rank displayed, and not a duplicate one?

Comment: @VladBalmos Alright. How would I go about imposing the overallxp into the query so the ranks would display correctly?

Comment: @Mko so you want the rank to be based on overall, and overallxp?

Comment: @VladBalmos In essence, yes. I want the primary sorting to be overall, but if 2+ users have the same overall, I want them to be sorted according to their overallxp.

Comment: what if overall and overallxp match?

Comment: @Dancrumb using the query i posted you won't get a tie. so if 2 users have the exact overalls they will be ranked by who comes first in the mysql results

Comment: MySQL uses quicksort which, when optimized, is not a stable sort. Therefore, you can't really rely on the ranking being the same for players with equal `overall` and `overallxp`. I'm interested in the OP's view on this... wouldn't it make sense to allow equal rankings?

Comment: @Dancrumb In theory it would, but no two users have the same overall value AND the same overallxp value. I think it'd be good just to rank the user who has more XP higher than a user with lower xp (and the same overall value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT rank FROM (
    SELECT @rank:=@rank + 1 AS rank, uid FROM playerstats ORDER BY overall DESC, 
    overallxp  DESC
) as tmp WHERE uid = 14950
```

the avove query will return the rank for user14950

This query will list all the users and their ranks

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT rank, uid, overall, overallxp FROM (
SELECT @rank:=@rank + 1 AS rank, uid, overall, overallxp FROM playerstats ORDER BY overall DESC, overallxp DESC
) as tmp
```

Comment: I'll try it out, however, this issue isn't only with uid14950. It exists for many other users, so there would need to be a check in place for duplicate overall results instead of having a WHERE conditional for only one occurrence.

Comment: the above snippet should eliminate that problem. just remove the where clause and you will have all the users and their ranks. i added the where just as an example on how to get the rank for a single user

Comment: I get an error saying:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT rank FROM (SELECT @rank:=@rank + 1 AS rank, uid FROM character_stats ORDE' at line 1

Comment: are you running the query from php or phpMyAdmin? post the exact query you are running. both my scripts run fine on my machine

Comment: I am running the query from PHP. My exact query:   $rank_query = mysqli_query($database, "SET @rank=0; SELECT rank, uid, overall, overallxp FROM (SELECT @rank:=@rank + 1 AS rank, uid, overall, overallxp FROM playerstats ORDER BY overall DESC, overallxp DESC) as tmp") or print(mysqli_error($database));

Comment: @Mko use mysqli_multi_query. mysqli_query doesn't handle multiple queries. see this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: After I executed the old query, I would display the results by: doing $rank_array = mysqli_fetch_array($rank_query); echo $rank_array[0];.    However, I get a warning using your code: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in [path]/personal.php on line 155
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command nowCommands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: this has deviated to a php related question. if the query runs fine in phpMyAdmin then it works. Consider posting another question with the related php problem

Comment: Alright, thanks a bunch for your help! :) I'll be posting another question soon, haha :D