# PHP MySQLi Multi Query - Commands Out of Sync: mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm currently creating a page in PHP that will display a user and their ranks in my site's high scores.

I had a problem where my MySQL query wasn't functioning as intended, however, @VladBalmos solved my problem here: [MySQL Highscores - User's Personal Ranks: Duplicate Entries Causing Incorrect Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091313/mysql-highscores-users-personal-ranks-duplicate-entries-causing-incorrect-va)

Now that I believe my MySQL query is functioning, I need to address the issues that arose with my PHP Code. Here is my code:

```
$userid = (int) $_GET['searched'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $skill_query = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT uid, overall, overallxp, gamelevel FROM playerstats WHERE uid = ". $userid ." ORDER BY playerstats.overall DESC, playerstats.overallxp DESC") or print(mysqli_error($database));
            $skill_array = mysqli_fetch_array($skill_query);
            //old rank query: $rank_query = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT count(*) + 1 FROM (SELECT uid, overall, overallxp, gamelevel FROM playerstats GROUP BY playerstats.uid) AS x WHERE overall > (SELECT overall FROM playerstats WHERE uid = ". $userid .")") or print(mysqli_error($database));
            $rank_query = mysqli_multi_query($database, "SET @rank=0; SELECT rank, uid, overall, overallxp FROM (SELECT @rank:=@rank + 1 AS rank, uid, overall, overallxp FROM playerstats ORDER BY overall DESC, overallxp DESC) as tmp") or print(mysqli_error($database));
            $rank_array = mysqli_fetch_array($rank_query);
        } else {
            $skill_query = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT uid, ". $skills[$i] .", gamelevel FROM playerstats WHERE uid = ". $userid ." ORDER BY playerstats.". $skills[$i] ." DESC, playerstats.gamelevel DESC") or print(mysqli_error($database));
            $skill_array = mysqli_fetch_array($skill_query);
            $rank_query = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT count(*) + 1 FROM (SELECT uid, ". $skills[$i] .", gamelevel FROM playerstats GROUP BY playerstats.uid) AS x WHERE ". $skills[$i] ." > (SELECT ". $skills[$i] ." FROM playerstats WHERE uid = ". $userid .")") or print(mysqli_error($database));
            $rank_array = mysqli_fetch_array($rank_query);
        }
    
        echo "<tr class='hs_row'>";
        echo "<td align='center'>";
        echo $rank_array[0]; //rank output
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>";
        echo $skill_array[1]; //skilllevel
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'>";
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo number_format($skill_array[2]); //skillxp
        } else {
            echo number_format($skill_array[1]); //skillxp
        }
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
```

...and the error I am receiving is:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in [path]/personal.php on line 156
>
> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in [path]/personal.php on line 159
>
> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in [path]/personal.php on line 161
>
> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

So, my question is, how do I correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rank_query = mysqli_multi_query($database, $yourQuery);
if($rank_query) {
    while(mysqli_next_result($dabatase)) {
        if($result = mysqli_store_result($database)) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) {
                // do something
            }
        }

    }
}
```

you have to loop through the results of your multiple queries and then access the rows for each result set. Since the first query just sets a variable you have to skip to the next result set and fetch the actual rows (that's why i did *while(mysqli_next_result...*)
read the docs at the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: Ah, I think I forgot the mysqli_next_result when I tried it. Thanks for the help! :)